# Sharepoint web feature show not activated in mange site feature page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-feature

I am activating the web feature through code 
web.Features.Add(new Guid("e03a943d-9a68-48cf-9a42-cb65be8fc4fb"));
The feature code is completed the execution but in the manage site feature page the feature show like not activated.

What is reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the add feature method is known to be a bit buggy.

It does not report exceptions even when it fails.

Things to check for:

1. Are you running this as Site Collection Admin?
2. Does this feature require other features to be enabled?
3. Check the ULS logs for errors, if needed include a custom tracer to make it easy to locate problems